# Why I do not get notified about duplication notice comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

My question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736) was voted to close as duplicated of another question, but I(tm) never got notified by the drop-down inbox, nor the SE inbox. Is this expected? Because if it's like this, most of our asker will think we didn't gave closure (as termination of the cycle) to their questions.

Comment: Got a link to the bug report?

Comment: @Seth http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210953

Answer (score 2):

You're not notified of close or delete votes in the drop down inbox.

Comment: Does that mean we should always post **one** comment when voting to close? Preferably the first voter would do that.

Comment: Good luck trying to enforce something like that.

Comment: Enforce? shudder ;-) - 'twas a question of what we as community should try to achieve (for ourselves).